# Error: Expected ‘struct tree_node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tree_node *’

Tags: c, linux

I'm facing two errors when trying to assign a value to the components of a struct and later when passing a pointer of struct to a function.

I have a user-defined data type: `my_node` defined in a header file as follows:

```
enum n_type
{
    N_COMMAND,
    N_PIPE,
    N_REDIRECT,
    N_SUBSHELL,
    N_SEQUENCE,
    N_DETACH
};


struct my_node;
typedef struct my_node node_t;

struct my_node
{
    enum n_type type;

    union {
        struct {
            char *program;
            char **argv;
            size_t argc;
        } command;

        struct {
            node_t **parts; // array
            size_t n_parts;
        } pipe;
        
        struct {
             ... etc
}
```

and I have a function that takes a pointer to a my_node variable:

```
void run_command(struct my_node *a_node);
```

In myprogram.c, I try to make a new node, populate its components, define a pointer to its address then pass the pointer to the function above like this:

```
// first I get input as a string:
fgets(str, 100, stdin);

// create the new node
struct my_node
{
    enum n_type type; 
    union
    { 
    struct {
        char *program;
        char **argv;
        size_t argc;
        } command;
    };
} node;

// assign values to its components (values are just for testing)
node.type = N_COMMAND;
node.command.program = &str;
node.command.argv = &node.command.program;
node.command.argc = 3;

// define a pointer to the node
struct my_node *ptr;
ptr = &node;

//pass the pointer to run command to execute it 
run_command(ptr);
```

When I try to compile, I get those weird errors:

```
gcc ./shell.c -o shelli
./shell.c: In function ‘main’:
./shell.c:37:23: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  node.command.program = &str;
                       ^
./shell.c:47:14: warning: **passing argument 1 of ‘run_command’ from incompatible pointer type** [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  run_command(ptr);
              ^~~
In file included from ./shell.c:2:0:
./shell.h:21:6: note: **expected ‘struct tree_node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct tree_node *’**
 void run_command(struct tree_node *n);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

How come that the provided and requested argument types are the same but still there's an error?

Comment: What is a `struct tree_node`? You never defined it, but is shows up in the compiler's error messages.

Comment: Since you've not shown code that reproduces the problem, we can't help resolve it.  There's a moderate chance that you are redefining `struct my_node` inside the scope of a function, and then attempting to pass a variable of the nested type to a function that takes the unnested type.  That's judging from the call to `fgets()` before a `struct my_node` definition.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
]

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `str`? My guess is that it's a `char*` since you used it as a parameter to `fgets`, and the compiler didn't complain. If that is the case, then

```
node.command.program = &str;
```

doesn't compile since `node.comand.program` has type `char*`, but the type of `&str` is `char**`. So, the solution is to remove the `&`, ie.

```
node.command.program = str;
```

The compile messages indicate a `struct tree_node` type, but that type isn't defined in your question. I'll assume it is similar to your `struct node` definition. With this assumption, the `run_command(ptr)` is a problem since you redefined what a `struct node` is in your source file. The redefinition is not compatible with the original definition in the header file. You should define a struct **only once** in a header file, and then include that header file in any source file that uses that struct.